# Query an Oracle table for existence of a 'batchnumber' before importing xml file with certain 'batchnumber' tag

Tags: xml, linux, oracle, shell, import

I'm currently working on a nice puzzle for a project, maybe some of you have already done something similar:

It needs to be a linux shell script

Here are the steps that need to be taken:

1. xml files are placed on linux database server (oracle)
2. xml files are validated (I've used xmllint, this works)
3. xml files contain a batchnumber, before importing, the batchnumber is not allowed to be present in the database, so how do I pass through a value from within a file into an sql query(maybe with an if..then...else clause?)

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

If the script user has access to sqlplus, you can execute it from the shell script and parse the results.

**batchnum.sql**

```
--  ==== batchnum.sql ===============
var bnum varchar2(32)
exec :bnum=&1
select count(*) from tablename where batchnumber=':bnum';
-- ========================
```

Execute command in your shell script with:

```
value=`sqlplus uname/pass @batchnum.sql 12345`
```

and then parse `$value` using `grep` or similar.

Notes:

- Untested code; I can't vouch for the syntax on the var/exec blocks
- I assumed `batchnum` was a `varchar2(32)`; you'll want to define it according to your actual type
- The var/exec construct is somewhat cumbersome, but uses bind variables. This allows Oracle's SQL parser to cache the query, which will be a performance gain for multiple successive invocations
- No exception handling; left as an exercise for you :)
- No validation of input parameters; also left as an exercise for you. Be sure to invoke this as a user with minimal permissions